# {{ drupal_view('view1', 'block_2') }} renders only when cache is cleared

Tags: views, 8, theming, blocks, caching

I like to output 2 block-views in a template called "block--bar.html.twig", but only when i clear the cache they are printed.

(i installed Twig Tweak 8.x-2.x)

This is the template:

```
<section{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
<div class="foo1">
{{ drupal_view('view1', 'block_2') }}
  </div>
<div class="foo2">
{{ drupal_view('view2', 'block_1') }}
  </div>
</section>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should disable Drupal 8 caching during development.
This link explain how to do it : https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914

Comment: it's a problem on the production site. i think it's not ok to disable cache on production?

Comment: It might be useful to know for beginners but this isn't a solution to the posters problem

Comment: Can you clarify? You clear cache then the blocks show, but if you reload the page the blocks disappear? Or they are just not updating or reflecting different paths/NID's? Is the block from the UI, or a module? A possible alternative to blocks in blocks might be https://www.drupal.org/project/viewsreference. This module is particularly successful when using paragraphs. Though it must be added to each node, where blocks can be easily placed site-wide.

Comment: it’s a block where i want to show 2 different views ( a pager and a page title).

Comment: when i rebuild the cache the block is shown, but when i open another page where the block should be showed, it is not. only when rebuild the cache again

Comment: @jimi could you please tell, do you have the contextual filters on your blocks? and give more details about your blocks. what kind of blocks they are?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the issue is to prevent that block to be cached. So first find the "block--bar.html.twig" and substitute in "add-block-id-name".

```
 /**
     * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for block.html.twig.
     */
    function YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
      if($vars['derivative_plugin_id'] == 'add-block-id-name') {
        //-- This stops the block being cache in drupal 8
        $vars['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;

      }
```

Comment: sorry, didn't worked. i reordered my views, so i didn't have to insert the view in a templates. Now it works fine.

Comment: what was you tried? because I'm fully sure, if you do it correctly it should work

Comment: function stgl_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
      if($vars['derivative_plugin_id'] == 'topblockbar') {
        //-- This stops the block being cache in drupal 8
        $vars['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;

      } }

Comment: or now i'm thinking, maybe i should have also replaced derivative_plugin_id with 'views" or something?

Comment: @jimi, you can dump the $vars there to see what you have. sorry in the delay to responding you. I was busy and haven't visited here.